# How to insert data in JSON using a query flavor?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

We assume the following json file

```
{

    "id": "test",
    "child" : [
                {    
                 "id": "alpha",
                 "child":[]
                },
                {    
                 "id": "beta",
                 "child":[]
                }

              ]

}
```

In JavaScript how can I insert a JSON object into a specific JSON array location using a query like flavor

I want to insert in the child where the neighbour id is alpha.

I don't want to use position

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by neighbor id? You mean you want to insert into the `beta` element because it's next to `alpha`?

Comment: This is not JSON, this is just JavaScript arrays and objects. JSON is a serialization format.

Comment: There's no query-like syntax for this. You can use `findIndex()` to get the position of an element that matches a condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a recursive function to insert an element at the specified index of your JSON object a like so:

```js
const yourJSON = `
{

    "id": "test",
    "child" : [
                {
                 "id": "alpha",
                 "child":[]
                },
                {
                 "id": "beta",
                 "child":[]
                }

              ]

}
`;

function insertIntoChildJSON(sourceJSON, childId, childPosition, value) {
    function insertIntoChild(data, childId, childPosition, value) {
        if (data.id === childId) {
            data.child[childPosition] = value;
        } else {
            if (data.child.length > 0) {
                for (let i = 0; i < data.child.length; ++i) {
                    data.child[i] = insertIntoChild(
                        data.child[i],
                        childId,
                        childPosition,
                        value
                    );
                }
            }
        }

        return data;
    }

    const parsedSource = JSON.parse(sourceJSON);

    return JSON.stringify(
        insertIntoChild(parsedSource, childId, childPosition, value)
    );
}

console.log(
    insertIntoChildJSON(yourJSON, 'alpha', 1, { id: 'charlie', child: [] })
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume `file.json` is your json string

```js
import objects from './file.json'
```

For querying, you could come up with something like this.

```
function query(column, value) {
  let children = objects.child
  return children.find(child => child[column] === value)
}
```

For multiple returns (array), use `filter` instead

```js
function query(column, value) {
  let children = objects.child
  return children.filter(child => child[column] === value)
}
```

Then inserting data would be:

```js
function insert(column, value, insert) {
  if (insert) {
    let children = objects.child
    let item = children.find(child => child[column] === value)
    if (variable.constructor === Array) {
      item.child.push(...insert)
    } else {
      item.child.push(insert)
    }
  }
}
```